# Convert time to fractional time matching this table - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, time

How do you convert time to fractional time based on a table?

Highlighted times are the problem by using `=PRODUCT()`

[image]

Comment: mathematically, the table rounds down when the minutes give .55, 65, .75, .85, .95. while it rounds up when the minutes gives .05, .15, .25, .35, .45. Building a condition to take this into account would also solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

In **F1** through **G60** create a two-column lookup table:

[image]

*(the two-column table allows Excel to get the info in your Report Fractions with a simple formula)*

Then put a time in **A1** and in **B1** enter:

```
=HOUR(A1)+VLOOKUP(MINUTE(A1),F1:G60,2,FALSE)
```

and apply a numeric format to ((B1**:

[image]

Comment: This is one of those times that the `[range_lookup]` toggle can be set to `true` which will allow a shortening of the `table_array` to the 10 returnable values.

Comment: +1 I have borrowed your method to shorten the lookup table for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Gary's Student's answer. This is a shorten version using `LOOKUP` function.

Create a lookup table of/for your fraction table that looks like this:

[image: Fractional table]

Then assuming your time is in cell A2 and the lookup table are in columns F and G, enter the following formula in B2:

```
=HOUR($A2)+LOOKUP(MINUTE($A2),$F$3:$F$13,$G$3:$G$13)
```

Drag the formula down the other cells.

[image]

Comment: A definite improvement *(+1)*